# How to create column that counts number of rows per each date of ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame that looks like this:

```
   id   datetime
0   a   2022-01-18
1   a   2022-01-19
2   a   2022-01-20
3   b   2022-01-20
4   b   2022-01-20
5   c   2022-01-18
```

and I want a DataFrame that looks something like:

```
    id  2022-01-20  2022-01-19   2022-01-18
0   a   1           1            1
1   b   2           0            0
2   c   0           0            1
```

I've tried

```
    df.groupby(['id', 'datetime']).size()
    
id  datetime
a   2022-01-18   1
    2022-01-19   1
    2022-01-20   1
b   2022-01-20   2
c   2022-01-18   1
```

It returns a series not a DataFrame which is close but still not what I want. Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: that is very close. how can I get pd.pivot(
    data=df, index='foo',  columns='bar', values= count(bar))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the following code

```
df = df.groupby(['id','date']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
df.columns.name = None
```

And as a result

```
df.head()

  id  2022-01-18  2022-01-19  2022-01-20
0  a           1           1           1
1  b           0           0           2
2  c           1           0           0
```